# Zend_Db_Table joined queries vs database view

Tags: php, zend-framework, coding-style, zend-db, zend-db-table

I was wondering what would be the best practices and the best way to achieve consistency while accessing your database data :

Current structure goes as follow

```
Data Access --> Business Logic --> Controller --> View
```

My data access layer is composed of a `Zend_Db_Table`, `Zend_Db_TableRowset` and a `Zend_Db_TableRow` for each table.

My business logic is stored in the model named based on a the `table`

Example of problematic query :

I want to get a specific user based on his username. To do so I have a `user` table and a `role` table (`role.id` is referred as `role_id` in the user table).

I don't want to have to use the `findDependentRowset` that will run additionnal queries for each row that get returned. (will get problematic in data grid that display the data as many rows can be returned).

The choices I have (getName() is used in this example to simplify, but it can be any processing) :

- Make a custom join on the role table in the user table which will return an `index array` composed of `associative array`. In that case I can't call my `getName()` function defined in my `Model_DbTable_User` to build the name (first name + middle + last name). Even if I "cast" my array to a `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` (or my custom table_rowset) I can't access my custom class method since I get a generic `Zend_Db_Table_Row` object.
- Make a custom join but build the name using `CONCAT()` in my query at runtime, I still get an array but the name is build so I don't need the `getName()` method. But if I have specific logic to apply i'm stuck.
- Make a view joining `user` and `role` tables in my database and create a new set of `Zend_DbTable`, `Zend_DbTableRowset` and `Zend_DbTableRow`. This way I can have specific logic in my database stack.
- An ORM (propel or doctrine (1 or 2)), I have no experience with these, I might need more informations to make the right choice.

My alternate goal is to be sure I get consistency in my data structures

ie:
array all the way :

```
array(
    array(row1), 
    array(row2)
);
```

object all the way

```
$row = $rowset->current();
$row->field;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a view should be done regardless because it complements the other ideas more than it competes with them. The view will:

- Abstract the database to something that you can more easily work with.
- Be faster because there's no parsing.
- Be accessible outside of your application.

Once you've created the views, you can choose a strategy that best solves the problem. If you're creating a form that represents a single entity, then an ORM is probably a good fit. But if you're displaying large lists of data or generating reports that contain many entities then using a declarative language like SQL is probably easier and would perform better.